# How in CSS can I do nested if/then

Tags: css

Beginner question. I have this code, which works fine

```
/* Start attribute labels bold */
.custom-attributes .attribute-label {
    font-weight: bold;
}
/*End attribute labels bold */

/* Start attribute value color */
.custom-attributes .attribute-value {
    color: red;
}
/* End attribute value color  */
```

Now, I'd like to filter the .custom-attributes .attribute-label and look for the value 1, then print all the .custom-attributes .attribute-value to this label green. So basically

I hope this is understandable... How can I do this?

This is for a wordpress website to customise the output on the website.

Comment: Reiterate your question. It doesn't make sense. CSS doesn't have any notion of an if statement. Further what do you mean with "look for the value" and "print".

Comment: You have to change the css through Javascript based on conditions. You can't do it through css... this is if I'm understanding your question properly.

Comment: attributes, class, id, position in the tree can be fitered by CSS, this the purpose of selector .  it is already alike IF `if the selector match do `  `if that selector match also then do also` ... there is no HTML of yours here to show what you try to select for specific style. **If** you clarify your question, **then** we might help

Comment: Thanks so far. I'm looking for something like this: if .custom-attributes .attribute-label = 1 then custom-attributes .attribute-value {color: red;} if .custom-attributes .attribute-label = 2 then custom-attributes .attribute-value {color: green;}

Comment: your answer stands here https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/attribute_selector/attribute~%3Dvalue :) i did not follow your link. html & css showing your issue should be in the question here .links can be broken or modified and question becomes useless for other user with similar issue.

Comment: As the others said, please show the HTML you want this CSS to apply to. Without it, we're just groping in the dark. In fact, it sounds now like you don't understand how HTML classes work. A class cannot have a value. So do you mean an _attribute_ with a certain value? If so, which one? Or does the element have a certain content? Or it is a list item with a certain number? We don't know!